# Is it possible to implement model inheritance in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, model, orm

For example I have `Question` model and `Reply` model. Both of them have methods with same names and similar functionality like `isDeclined`, `isSeen` etc.
As it already extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` how can I share some methods and avoid code duplication ?
The only thing comes in mind is to use traits but inheritance seems more flexible solution, wonder if it is possible to implement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own abstract model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.
Let's call it `Namespace_Module_Model_Abstract` that contains the methods `isDeclined` and `isSeen` and maybe others.
Then you can have your `Question` and `Reply` models extend `Namespace_Module_Model_Abstract`.
The same approach is taken in the core module `Catalog` where there is a [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php) class that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and the product and category model extend this `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` class.